# How to limit the range of the x-axis with imshow()?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have the following data

```
1.105   0.919   0.842   0.715   0.704   0.752   0.827   1.049   0.584   
0.998   0.931   0.816   0.787   0.803   0.856   0.782   0.872   0.710   
1.268   1.189   1.036   0.984   0.847   0.948   1.083   0.864   0.792
```

that I plot with `imshow()`

The result looks like this:
[image]

Here is my code:

```
from numpy import*
import matplotlib.cm as cm
import matplotlib.mlab as mlab
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import make_axes_locatable

shape=(3,9)
velocity=zeros(shape)


fig = plt.figure(figsize=(16, 12), dpi=100)
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111,aspect='equal')
#   ax1.set_yticks([int(100*j) for j in range(0,4)])
ax1.set_yticks([int(j) for j in range(0,4)])
ax1.set_xticks([int(j) for j in range(-4,5)])
for label in ax1.get_xticklabels() + ax1.get_yticklabels():
    label.set_fontsize(15)
for tick in ax1.get_xticklines() + ax1.get_yticklines():
    tick.set_markeredgewidth(2)
    tick.set_markersize(6)
ax1.set_aspect("equal") 
velocity=loadtxt("fieldvelocitybot-300-100-100_400.dat")

im = plt.imshow(velocity, cmap=cm.jet, interpolation='nearest',origin='lower',vmin=0,vmax=1.7, extent=[-4.50,4.50,0.,3.00])

divider = make_axes_locatable(ax1)
cax = divider.append_axes("right", size="2.5%", pad=0.3)
cb=plt.colorbar(im,cax=cax)
cb.set_label('Speed [$m/s$]')
plt.savefig("speed_400.png")
plt.close(fig)
```

My problem is: How to show just the results from -4 to 4? Intuitively I thought of changing `extent=[-4.00,4.00,0.,3.00]`, but the axis is then just shifted. The result is like this:
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Setting the extent for imshow is good, since this defines the range of your data. It does not specify the range of what is shown, because this is a property of the axes and can be set by simply adding ax1.set_xlim(-4,4)

So:

```
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import make_axes_locatable
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

velocity=np.random.rand(3,9)

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(1,1,figsize=(16, 12), dpi=100, subplot_kw={'aspect': 'equal'})

ax1.set_yticks([int(j) for j in range(0,4)])
ax1.set_xticks([int(j) for j in range(-4,5)])

for label in ax1.get_xticklabels() + ax1.get_yticklabels():
    label.set_fontsize(15)
for tick in ax1.get_xticklines() + ax1.get_yticklines():
    tick.set_markeredgewidth(2)
    tick.set_markersize(6)

im = ax1.imshow(velocity, cmap=cm.jet,     interpolation='nearest',origin='lower',vmin=0,vmax=1.7, extent=[-4.50,4.50,0,3])
ax1.set_xlim(-4,4)

divider = make_axes_locatable(ax1)
cax = divider.append_axes("right", size="2.5%", pad=0.3)
cb=plt.colorbar(im,cax=cax)
cb.set_label('Speed [$m/s$]')

plt.savefig("speed_400.png")
plt.close(fig)
```

[image]

Comment: probably, you forgot to mention colormap(cm)  `from matplotlib import cm` Thanks